# Spritestage and multiple spritesheets

Tags: html, webgl, createjs, easeljs

My team is currently working on a rather large Web application. We have switched from the flash platform to Html5 in hope for a one size fits all platform.

The UI, is mainly based on createjs, which I by the way really enjoy working with.

However we have now reached the maturity phase and started optimizing some of the animations, that doesn't run smoothly in especially IE.

The thing is that we have a around 1500 sprites (pngs & jpgs) which is drawn onto a stage. We only draw around 60 of them per frame. 
They are rather large (up to 800x800 pixels), and the application engine can choose which 60 to show more or less randomly.

The images are packed in a zip file and unpacked in the browser and Html images are constructed by converting the binary data to a base64 encoded string, which is passed to the src property of an image.

So in each frame render a set of around 
60 images are drawn to the stage. And this is for some reason slow.

I have therefore used some time to experiment with the Spritestage of createjs to take advantage of Webgl, but with only small improvements.

So now I'm considering to pack our sprites in a spritesheet, which results in many sheets because of the large amount of data.

My question is therefore: 
Would spritestage gain any improvements if my sprites are spread across multiple sheets? According to the documentation only spritesheets with a single image are supported.

Best regards
/Mikkel Rasmussen

Answer (score 0):

In general, spritesheets speed up rendering by decrease the number of draw call required by frame. Instead of say, using a different texture and render for every sprite, spritesheet implementations can draw multiple sprites with one render call, provided that the sprite sheet contains all the different individual sprite images. So to answer your question, you are unlikely to see performance gains if the sprites you want to draw are scattered on different sprite sheets.

Draw calls have significant overhead and it is generally a good idea to minimize them. 1500 individual draw calls would be pretty slow.

I dont know if it this is applicable to your situation but it is possible your bottleneck is not the number of draw calls you dispatch to GPU but you are doing too much overdraw since you mention your sprites are 800x800 each. If that is the case, try to render front to back with the depth test or stencil test turned on.

Comment: Is the stencil test and depth test Webgl concepts? If so I would expect createjs to use this behind the scenes. I only have little knowledge about the details of webgl, which is why I prefer to use a library like createjs to avoid getting my hands too dirty.

Comment: @MikkelRasmussen Have you had any luck finding the answer to that?